# Где найти нормальную документацию по powershell?

Tags: powershell

Нормальную, это как для python, например. По которой реально научиться можно.
Потому что сейчас банальное

```
 Отсутствует аргумент в списке параметров.
     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

вызывает кучу непонимания и практически никак не гуглится.

Документацию искал тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/

Comment: Такая ошибка может возникать, когда Вы пропустили аргумент перед бинарным оператором массива `,`. Например: `echo, fgh`.

Comment: покажите, что вы делаете

Comment: А каковы критерии нормальности в понимании задавшего вопрос? Во встроенной документации все очень четко изложено, если этого кажется мало, тогда лучше обратиться к вспомогательной литературе.

Comment: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=PVQoDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PR10#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=78w1953mptUC&lpg=PP1&dq=inauthor%3A%22Lee%20Holmes%22&pg=PR15#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что я искал, называется "спецификацией по языку PowerShell", скачать можно, например, тут:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36389